# How do I instantiate this piece of code properly?

Tags: python, oop, arguments, instantiation, instantiation-error

I want to instantiate the two child classes by declaring M,F as variables. From there, I want to print the genders for the resulting instances.

I am following examples closely and I cannot discern why my code doesn't work and I keep getting the error: "get_gender() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

I would appreciate any advice

```
class Person:

    class Male(Person):
        
        def get_gender(self):
            print("male")
            

    class Female(Person):
        
        def get_gender(self):
            print("female")
            
M = Male()          # instance
F = Female()        # instance

M.get_gender()
F.get_gender()
```

Comment: This code does not work *at all*. The class ``Person`` does not exist by the time ``Male`` and ``Female`` are defined, and thus they cannot inherit from it. This code *cannot* produce the error shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Male` and `Female` shouldn't be nested inside the parent class `Person`.

```
class Person:
    pass

class Male(Person):
    
    def get_gender(self):
        print("male")
        

class Female(Person):
    
    def get_gender(self):
        print("female")
            
M = Male()          # instance
F = Female()        # instance

M.get_gender()
F.get_gender()
```